# How to copy directory from remote server with scp, excluding a specific subdirectory

Tags: linux, copy, scp, remote-server, subdirectory

I have a directory that I want to copy from a remote server to my desktop. In this directory there is a 40Gb subdirectory that I want to exclude from copying. Until now I used the `scp` command but there is no `-exclude` option or anything similar in the `man` page. By looking online I found a bunch of different ways to copy directory from remote host or exclude a subdirectory when copying locally but no way of how to combine those two. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy with excluding some file or folder, you should try *rsync* command.

There is *--exclude-dir* option you can use to exclude subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you can't use rsync (on a readonly system for exemple) is to tar over ssh.

```sh
tar \
  --exclude='temp' \
  --exclude='work' \
  --exclude='logs' \
  -cpf \. # c: create p: preserve owner f: dest file... is output stream
  - \
  apache-tomcat-9.0.17 \. # file or folder to compress/send through ssh
     | ssh foo@bar.com '(cd ~/my/save/directory; tar xfp - )'
```